# Class naming based on version of data

Tags: .net, naming-conventions

I have a library which parses various messages, sent in binary form from multiple devices. Devices are still in active development, and their firmware is changed often, which forces me to support different variations of the protocol for all existing versions.

Let's say that a message prior to revision looked like this:

```
INFO XXXX YYYY CRC
```

and after firmware version 50, it changed to:

```
INFO XXXX YYYY ZZZZ CRC
```

Does it make sense to name my parser classes like this:

```
class InfoParser : IParser<IInfoMessage>
{ ... }

class InfoParserRev50 : IParser<IInfoMessage> 
{ ... }
```

They are both doing a similar things, and they need to coexist, and these changes **happen all the time**, but I was wondering if there is a better way of naming them?

Comment: imho the name is just fine and informative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's perfectly acceptable to maintain different versions of you classes if you need to support different versions of parsing at the same time. You can combine this with some sort of dispatch logic to tie it all together. In this way you can support multiple versions simultaneously, and avoid issues that may be associating with trying to specialize your parsers as the specifications evolve e.g. fiendishly nested and long if\else statments, for example.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's the general idea. Most of the time, changes allow me to reuse the base parser and implement the change only, without touching existing parser code. My only concern is that naming looks a bit weird. I thought of adding a descriptive suffix (e.g. `InfoWithAdditionFieldParser` sort of name), but this would get really messy after a couple of revisions.

Comment: @Groo If you can organize some common parsing code great, the trick is that this must be stable otherwise bugs can be easily introduced to other parsers if devices have slight quirks. I think naming your classes so they can be traced back to the device versions would be sensible and self-documenting.

Comment: Well, each parser version still has it's own set of unit tests, which don't change when I add a new class version. I keep all previous tests green with my changes (otherwise we would have gone mad a long time ago, with all the changes taking place).

Comment: @Groo Sounds to me like you're on the right track. I have used a similar approach before with a SOA where we had to support multiple XML document versions simultaneously. Same sorts of issues with parsing, etc. We included document version information in the class names. KISS.